# Android checking network operator upon installation

Tags: android

I am building an android app, which is restricted to users only using a particular telecom network. And i don't want users who are not on that network to be able to install the app.

So i wanted to know if it is possible to check on which network operator the user is when installing the app.

Thanks.

Comment: Obviously, no, as your app is not running upon installation ...

Comment: you can halt the user after installation if the user is not from your intended network. That's easy solution i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The app cannot run any code while it is installing, or, before installation. Any code will be executed after the app is installed.
What you can do is, after the app is installed, check for network operator. If it is the desired one, let the user use the app. Else, deny any further access.
You can also ask the user to uninstall the app by creating a new `Intent` with `Intent.ACTION_DELETE` and specifying the package name. It will give the user an option to uninstall the app.